# phpstormで日本語が入力されているファイルを開くと文字がずれている

Tags: phpstorm

日本語を含むファイルをvimではきれいに揃っているのに、phpstormで開くとずれてしまっている、ということがあります。

[image: vimで表示]

[image: phpstormで表示]

日本語を含むファイル以外の時は問題ありません。
設定の方法等知っている方がいらっしゃいましたら教えて頂けると幸いです。

実際のコードは下記になります（phpstormからコピーアンドペースト致しました。）

```
        case 'ＪＲ中央本線(立川－甲府)':    return ['ＪＲ中央線'];
        case 'ＪＲ中央線快速':              return ['ＪＲ中央線快速'];
        case 'ＪＲ中央線青梅特快':          return ['ＪＲ中央線快速', 'ＪＲ青梅線'];
        case 'ＪＲ中央線中央特快':          return ['ＪＲ中央線快速'];
        case 'ＪＲ総武線':                  return ['ＪＲ中央線・総武線各駅停車', 'ＪＲ総武線快速'];
        case 'ＪＲ五日市線':                return ['ＪＲ五日市線'];
        case 'ＪＲ京浜東北・根岸線快速':    return ['ＪＲ京浜東北線'];
        case 'ＪＲ京葉線':                  return ['ＪＲ京葉線'];
```

vimからコピーアンドペーストしたものが下記です。(vim上ではきれいにうつっていますが、コピーアンドペーストをするとズレが発生致しました。)

```
        case 'ＪＲ中央本線(立川－甲府)':    return ['ＪＲ中央線'];
        case 'ＪＲ中央線快速':              return ['ＪＲ中央線快速'];
        case 'ＪＲ中央線青梅特快':          return ['ＪＲ中央線快速', 'ＪＲ青梅線'];
        case 'ＪＲ中央線中央特快':          return ['ＪＲ中央線快速'];
        case 'ＪＲ総武線':                  return ['ＪＲ中央線・総武線各駅停車', 'ＪＲ総武線快速'];
        case 'ＪＲ五日市線':                return ['ＪＲ五日市線'];
        case 'ＪＲ京浜東北・根岸線快速':    return ['ＪＲ京浜東北線'];
        case 'ＪＲ京葉線':                  return ['ＪＲ京葉線'];
        case 'ＪＲ京葉線快速':              return ['ＪＲ京葉線'];
```

■バージョン情報
vim : version 7.4.488 
phpstorm : version 8.0.2
OS : OSX 10.10.2

■動作環境
vimはmacのローカル環境で使用しています。phpstormに関しても同様のPC上で開いております。

Comment: 画像だけでなく、該当部分のコードを直接貼り付けていただけると回答しやすくなるかと思います。
あと、環境の情報（OS, vimは端末上なのかgvimなのか、使用フォントなど）もあると回答の参考になると思います。

Comment: phpstormとvimで使用しているフォントは何でしょうか？もしかしたら、日本語に対応した等幅フォントを使用すれば治るかもしれません

Comment: @Miyako
ありがとうございます。該当部分のコードは、

```php
            case 'ＪＲ中央本線(立川－甲府)':return ['ＪＲ中央線'];
            case 'ＪＲ中央線快速':         return ['ＪＲ中央線快速'];
            case 'ＪＲ中央線青梅特快':          return ['ＪＲ中央線快速', 'ＪＲ青梅線'];
            case 'ＪＲ中央線中央特快':          return ['ＪＲ中央線快速'];
            case 'ＪＲ総武線':                  return ['ＪＲ中央線・総武線各駅停車', 'ＪＲ総武線快速'];
            case 'ＪＲ五日市線':                return ['ＪＲ五日市線'];
```

で、フォントは、

* phpstorm : menlo
* vim : monaco

です。フォントを両方monacoに揃えて実験してみましたが、問題は解決されませんでした。

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。回答させていただきました。コードやフォントの情報は、本文の方に追加すると後で見た方もわかりやすくて良いと思います。あと、フォントが絡む問題なので、OSの情報もあったほうが良いでしょう。また、回答の方に書きましたが、vimは端末上とgvim/macvimで動作が異なったりするので、（Vimに限りませんが）ソフトウェアのバージョンや動作環境などももう少し詳しく書いてあるとより回答が得られやすくなると思います。

あと、書いていただいたコード、本文の画像のものと違いませんか？画像では`...立川-甲府)':`と`return`の間に空白がありますが、書いていただいたコードでは空白がありませんし、vimでも揃いません。タブ文字は投稿時にスペースに置き換えられるようなので、その影響かもしれませんが。

Comment: @Miyako ありがとうございます。こちら本文に貼り直しました。こちら本文にペーストしている際に文字にズレが発生致しました。その他sublimeテキストやmac純正のテキストエディットに貼り付けてみたりしましたが、同様にズレが発生致しました。
そのためphpstorm側の問題というよりはvimで適切に日本語の設定がされている、と考えております（行った覚えがないので最初から設定がなされているのかもしれません）。
phpstorm側でも設定をしたいのですが、引き続きどのような設定項目なのかイメージがついていないという状況です。

Comment: 解決できたようでよかったです。余談ですが、本文でずれるのも私が回答に書いたのと似た理由です。コード部分のフォント指定が優先度順に`consolas,Menlo,Meslo,...`となっていますが、日本語等幅フォントは指定されていません。私の環境(OS X, Chrome 40)では英字が Menlo、日本語がOsaka（ブラウザのデフォルト設定）で描画されていました。等幅フォントでもフォントが違えば文字幅は異なりますので、ブラウザの画面上でもズレが生じているのでしょう。 参考: [javascript - 要素に適用されている実際のフォントを知るには？ - スタック・オーバーフロー](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/2945/%e8%a6%81%e7%b4%a0%e3%81%ab%e9%81%a9%e7%94%a8%e3%81%95%e3%82%8c%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b%e5%ae%9f%e9%9a%9b%e3%81%ae%e3%83%95%e3%82%a9%e3%83%b3%e3%83%88%e3%82%92%e7%9f%a5%e3%82%8b%e3%81%ab%e3%81%af)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

monacoを使われていることとVimの表示から、OS XとMacVimの組み合わせと仮定して以下回答します。

フォントの問題だと思います。フォントを両方Osaka-Mono（またはOsakaでレギュラー-等幅を選択）に設定してみてください。

Vimのフォントの設定方法がわからなければ、 `:set guifont=*` で一覧が表示されるので選んでください。または`:set guifont=Osaka−等幅:h11`などでも設定できます。PHPStromの方は使っていないので設定方法はわかりませんが、<s>おそらく難しく無いと思います</s>**難しそうなので代替案を追記しました**。
OSがWindowsの場合はMSゴシック、Linuxの場合はIPA Gothicなどを選択してください。

```
|12345678901234567890|
|１２３４５６７８９０|
|一二三四五六七八九零|
```

使われているフォントが等幅フォントであれば、上記三行を貼り付けた時に右端が揃うはずです。

一応理由も書いておきます。間違っているかもしれませんが。

monacoもmenloも日本語を含んでいないので、おそらく今は日本語にだけシステムがあてがった別のフォントが使われています。Vimの画像で極端にフォントが幅広になっていることから、使われている日本語フォントがプロポーショナルフォントなのでしょう。Vimでは`:set guifont`や`:set guifontwide`を実行すると、実際に使われているフォントの情報が出るはずです。私の経験上、MacVimやLinux上のGVimでは、プロポーショナルフォントも何故か設定できて、このように無理やり幅を広くとって等幅になるように描画するようです。なので、プロポーショナルフォントもそのままの幅で描画するPHPStromで表示がずれたのだと思いました。

- 追記: PHPStormでフォントにOsaka-Monoを指定するのが難しい場合

PHPStormと同じJetBrains製のPyCharmで試したところ、スタイル指定ができずOsaka-Monoに設定するのが難しそうだったので、無理でしたら他の日本語等幅フォントを試してみてください。[Ricty Diminished](https://github.com/yascentur/RictyDiminished)は等幅フォントしか含んでいないので確実だと思います。日本語等幅フォントは他にも探せばいくつか見つかると思います。

Comment: phpstormをRicty Diminishedに設定をしたらきちんと等幅できれいに表示されました！ありがとうございます！プロポーショナルフォントなど大変勉強になりました^^

Answer (score 1):

PHPStormの表示設定で、タブ間隔を調整してみてはいかがでしょう。

Comment: tabを使わず半角スペースで揃えても問題が解決されなかったので、おそらくtab設定の問題ではないかとおもわれます。

Answer (score 1):

`Vim` のほうのシングルクォーテーションが、半角記号なのにまるで全角のように幅広く取っているように見えます。

そこから類推するに、`Vim` と `PhpStorm` でフォントの設定が違っているのではないでしょうか？
フォントを揃えれば同じように見えるようになると思います。

Comment: フォントは

 * phpstorm : menlo 
 * vim : monaco

で、どちらもmonacoにして実験してみましたが、問題は解決されませんでした。